# Dynamic Encryption key in CodeIgniter 3 config

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I am trying to follow the instruction of CI 3 docs about encryption https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html#setting-your-encryption-key 
 I apply the instruction but it won't make pretty output like I want, here is the standard code

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
$key = $this->encryption->create_key(16);
// Get a hex-encoded representation of the key:
$key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));

// Put the same value in your config with hex2bin(),
// so that it is still passed as binary to the library:
$config['encryption_key'] = hex2bin(<your hex-encoded key>);
```

but i am getting this error
[image: error config]

how to solve this error? or I am writing some wrong code?

Comment: ```$this``` is an instance of your controller class. You can't use it in config.

You have take instance of like ```$CI =& get_instance();``` and then call ```$CI->load->library('encryption'); $key = $CI->encryption->create_key(16);```

Comment: I think you are writing the code in ```config.php```, instead write your code in controller.

Comment: For your codeigniter enc key https://randomkeygen.com/

Comment: maybe this picture would explain my confusion @kishor10d  https://snag.gy/8nsN0Q.jpg

Comment: i think encryption_key in config file could be generated dynamically, could it be??

Comment: user  $this->config->set_item('encryption_key', $key); in your controller to set the key

Comment: thanks bro, so this code must be set in controller? @pradeep why i asking this question is because i'm aware about this STATIC ENCRYPTION_KEY SYNDROME in this article https://www.mehmetince.net/codeigniter-based-no-cms-admin-account-hijacking-rce-via-static-encryption-key/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key. and dynamic Encryption key must be set on indivisible controller file.single Encryption key set on config.php file

//single encryption key
$config['encryption_key'] = '';

//dynamic encryption key 
$this->load->library('encryption'); //load encryption library in your controller

$key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));

$config['encryption_key'] = hex2bin();